# Firefox WebExtension notifications API: How to call a function when the notification is clicked

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to develop a Firefox add on using WebExtensions. What I'm trying to do is open a new Firefox tab or window when the user clicks the notification. But it doesn't work.

When I click the notification, nothing happens.

I'm creating notifications like:

```js
var q = chrome.notifications.create({
  "type": "basic",
  "iconUrl": chrome.extension.getURL("128-128q.png"),
  "title": 'title',
  "message": 'content'
 });
 
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
});
browser.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
});
 
q.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
});
 
var audio = new Audio('message.mp3');
audio.play();
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is that you are attempting to open a new URL in a way that does not work.

The following should work, using [`chrome.tabs.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Tabs/create):

```
var q = chrome.notifications.create("MyExtensionNotificationId", {
        "type": "basic",
        "iconUrl": chrome.extension.getURL("128-128q.png"),
        "title": 'title',
        "message": 'content'
    });

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com"});
});
```

However, you need to be testing this in Firefox 47.0+ as support for [`chrome.notifications.onClicked()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/onClicked) was only added recently. My statement of Firefox 47.0+ is based on the compatibility table. However, the compatibility table has at least one definite error. Thus, a higher version of Firefox may be required. The code I tested worked in Firefox Nightly, version 50.0a1, but did not work properly in Firefox Developer Edition, version 48.0a2. In general, given that the WebExtensions API is in active development, you should be testing against Firefox Nightly if you have questions/issues which are not functioning as you expect. You can also check the [source code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/extensions/ext-notifications.js) for the API to see what really is implemented and when it was added.

**Note:** this works with either `chrome.notifications.onClicked` or `browser.notifications.onClicked`. However, don't use both to add two separate anonymous functions which do the same thing as doing so will result in whatever you are doing happening twice.

I did not actually test it with your code, but I did test it with a modified version of the [notify-link-clicks-i18n WebExtensions example](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n).  I modified the *background-script.js* file from that example to be:

```
/*
Log that we received the message.
Then display a notification. The notification contains the URL,
which we read from the message.
*/
function notify(message) {
    console.log("notify-link-clicks-i18n: background script received message");
    var title = chrome.i18n.getMessage("notificationTitle");
    var content = chrome.i18n.getMessage("notificationContent", message.url);
    let id = "notify-link-clicks-i18n::" + title + "::" + message.url;
    chrome.notifications.create(id,{
        "type": "basic",
        "iconUrl": chrome.extension.getURL("icons/link-48.png"),
        "title": title,
        "message": content
    });
}

/*
Assign `notify()` as a listener to messages from the content script.
*/
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify);

//Add the listener for clicks on a notification:
chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(notificationId) {
    console.log("Caught notification onClicked with ID:" + notificationId);
    //Open a new tab with the desired URL:
    browser.tabs.create({url:"http://www.google.com"});
});
```

My preference for something like this where a unique [ID is possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Notifications/create) is to provide a unique ID, that both identifies that the notification was displayed by my add-on and what the notification was. This allows the listener function to choose to only act on notifications which were displayed by my add-on and/or only a subset of those I display, or have different actions based on why I displayed the notification.

The reason you had trouble here in figuring out what was not working is probably because you did not reduce the issue to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue. In other words, it would have been a good idea to just try opening a new URL separately from the notifications onClicked listener and just try a `console.log()` within the listener.